# Parsing JSON Data Sent from Calendly.com

Tags: php, json, webhooks, calendly

I am trying to send data sent by [calendly.com](http://calendly.com) to my webserver. I am connecting to that webserver and can post data to it just fine using

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$myvars = 'first_name=' . $full_name . '&email=' . $thisemail;
```

However, I am having difficulty getting data into `$myvars`. I have tried this

```
$data = $_REQUEST['payload'];           
$unescaped_data = stripslashes($data);
$obj = json_decode($unescaped_data);
$thisemail = $obj->invitee->email;
$full_name = $obj->invitee->name;
```

But that variable doesn't populate. I have also changed the

```
$data = $_REQUEST['payload']
```

to

```
$data = $_POST['payload']
```

I have also tried a totally different approach

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$thisemail = $request["payload"]["invitee"]["email"];
```

When I just put in dummy string in `$thisemail` and `$full_name` it works as expected.

I also read that this data is `gzip` encoded. So I did also try to change this

```
$request = json_decode($json, true);
```

to this

```
$request = gzdecode($json);
```

but also with no effect.

Here is a snippet of what the data is supposed to be looking like

```
{
  "event":"invitee.created",
  "time":"2016-08-23T19:16:01Z",
  "payload":{
    "event_type":{
      "kind":"1-on-1",
      "slug":"event_type_name",
      "name":"Event Type Name",
      "duration":15
    },
    "event":{
      "uuid":"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
      "assigned_to":[
        "Jane Sample Data"
      ],
      "extended_assigned_to": [
        "name": "Jane Sample Data",
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "primary": false
      ],
      "start_time":"2016-08-23T12:00:00Z",
      "start_time_pretty":"12:00pm - Tuesday, August 23, 2016",
      "invitee_start_time":"2016-08-23T12:00:00Z",
      "invitee_start_time_pretty":"12:00pm - Tuesday, August 23, 2016",
      "end_time":"2016-08-23T12:15:00Z",
      "end_time_pretty":"12:15pm - Tuesday, August 23, 2016",
      "invitee_end_time":"2016-08-23T12:15:00Z",
      "invitee_end_time_pretty":"12:15pm - Tuesday, August 23, 2016",
      "created_at":"2016-08-23T00:00:00Z",
      "location":"The Coffee Shop",
      "canceled":false,
      "canceler_name":null,
      "cancel_reason":null,
      "canceled_at":null
    },
    "invitee":{
      "uuid":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
      "first_name":"Joe",
      "last_name":"Sample Data",
      "name":"Joe Sample Data",
      "email":"not.a.real.email@example.com",

     ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@blewherself's answer brings to light the important fact that the JSON in the example found [here](http://developer.calendly.com/docs/sample-webhook-data) is not valid JSON and I have upvoted their answer for that reason.

After further investigation, however, I do believe that this is an error of that page alone and that the actual JSON passed by them is not invalid. However, I am happy to add here my answer that I found after much persistence as I believe that the documentation at [calendly.com](http://calendly.com) is too brief to be very useful.

The JSON file can be retrieved with `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and otherwise you can access the individual components more or less according to the example in the docs, at least the part I was interested in. Like so

```
$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);
$full_name = $data["payload"]["invitee"]["name"];
$thisemail = $data["payload"]["invitee"]["email"];
$first_name = explode(" ", $full_name)[0];
$last_name = explode(" ", $full_name)[1];
```

You'll notice a glaring omission that their form asks customers: phone number. It appears that even though the client is asked for it, it is not passed to your url in the JSON file. Also, though first and last name are given as a passed item in the JSON example in the docs, neither it nor many other items in the example are asked for in their form. I am not sure how they expect that data to be passed in their JSON. I sincerely hope the folks at [calendly](http://calendly.com) address these issues soon.

Comment: "In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives." Source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not valid.
Square brackets are used for arrays ex. `["Jane", "John", "Jack"]`
Braces are used for objects ex. `{"name": "John", "surname" : "Wick"}`

Try

```
"extended_assigned_to": {
    "name": "Jane Sample Data",
    "email": "user@example.com",
                "primary": false
            },
```

Instead of

```
  "extended_assigned_to": [
                "name": "Jane Sample Data",
                "email": "user@example.com",
                "primary": false
            ],
```

In this case you can write a function that corrects mistakes in encoded JSON before feeding it to JSON decode. I've written a function that would handle it for you using regular expression. It is searching for all cases where colon is placed in square brackets and replaces them with braces. Should work with any number of such cases in one response. Hope it will help.

```
function correctJSON ($string) {
//Get an array of all cases with invalid brackets
    preg_match_all('/\[".*":.*\]/', $string, $matches);

//Create an array with braces with inside content to replace with       
    for($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++) {
        $replace[$i] = str_replace(array('[',']'), array('{','}'), $matches[0][$i]);    
    }

//Replace
    return $string = str_replace($matches[0], $replace, $string);
}
```

P.S. One can't just replace square brackets with braces straight away in the source. It will replace arrays `["Jane", "John", "Jack"]` with `{"Jane", "John", "Jack"}` that is not valid JSON either.

Comment: I don't have any control over the JSON. It is posted to my page by the folks at calendly.com.

Comment: I've verified your JSON snippet at jsonlint.com and it says JSON is not valid. As soon as it's not valid you'll get NULL after using json_decode. I believe that's why you can't get data from your request.

Comment: It's not the complete JSON. I wonder if it would be valid if you put in the entire JSON. For the complete JSON, you can go [here](http://developer.calendly.com/docs/sample-webhook-data).

Comment: In any case, if calendly.com isn't sending me valid JSON, then I really am not sure what to do about that.

Comment: It's valid except of the "extended_assigned_to" object that should be placed in { } instead of [ ]. I believe you had to write down a regular expression to replace brackets before using json_decode.

I'll try to help in a couple of hours

Comment: OK. Thanks. I think I need to report this issue to calendly.com.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for this. Another issue with the same problem has crept up, so I will have to check on it later. I upvoted if for no other reason than the fact that you pointed out that the api provide some invalid JSON.

Comment: Can you get a JSON response to check if it's invalid again?

Comment: I'm also doubt that your $_REQUEST['payload'] is working correctly. JSON is sent in response as a string by default. So if server sends you an object with 'event', 'time' and 'payload' you probably can't get it stratight away from the string in the response. If it is a case you should get request in whole, decode it and only after try to get 'payload'. 

`$obj->payload->invitee->email` is working as intended in my tests.

By the way, calendly.com should have already changed mistake in JSON. At least they had changed Sample Webhook Data page in their Docs you had linked to.